# How add OpenGL & GLUT for CLion on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, clion, glut

I have installed OpenGL and Glut but when I'm trying to run it - get this error. Have I installed something wrong? Or should I edit CMake file?

### CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(LW1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(OpenGL)
include_directories(OpenGL/include) # OpenGL/include has to contain the required OpenGL's .h files
include_directories(OpenGL/lib) # OpenGL/lib has to contain the required OpenGL's .lib files



add_custom_target(glutdlllib
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy LW1/OpenGL/dll/glut32.dll ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        )

set(OpenGlLibs glaux glu32 glui32 glut32 opengl32 )


#These 3 lines are just linking and making executables

add_executable(LW1 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(LW1 ${OpenGlLibs})

add_dependencies(LW1 glutdlllib)

target_link_libraries(LW1 -lOpenGL32 -lfreeGLUT)
```

### main.cpp :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glaux.h>
#include <glut.h>

void resize(int width, int height)
{
}
void display(void) {
    glColor3d(1,1,0);
    glutSolidSphere(1.0, 25, 25);
    glFlush();
}
void init(void) {
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);;
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0, 2.0, 12.0);
    gluLookAt(0,0,5, 0,1,0, 0,1,0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 10);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello");
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

### Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.2.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Anichaaaaaa\CLionProjects\LW1\cmake-build-debug --target LW1 -- -j 6
Error copying file "LW1/OpenGL/dll/glut32.dll" to "C:/Users/Anichaaaaaa/CLionProjects/LW1/cmake-build-debug".
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\glutdlllib.dir\build.make:76: CMakeFiles/glutdlllib] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/glutdlllib.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:130: CMakeFiles/LW1.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:150: LW1] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The command in `add_custom_target` is executed with the working directory set to your build directory. The relative path you give is thus interpreted as relative to the build directory.

Either set the working directory to `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` or use it convert the relative path to an absolute one in your copy command.

Comment: Thanks! But I also faced up with an error `Error copying file "CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR/OpenGL/dll/glut32.dll" to "C:/Users/Anichaaaaaa/CLionProjects/LW1/cmake-build-debug".
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\glutdlllib.dir\build.make:76: CMakeFiles/glutdlllib] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/glutdlllib.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:130: CMakeFiles/LW1.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:150: LW1] Error 2`

Comment: It is a variable, so you need to write `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. I did not mention that as you already use variables in your cmake file.